# Cucumber - Steps are highlighted as not defined

Tags: cucumber, bdd

In cucumber, my steps are highlighted as not defined, 
but in actual I have defined those steps and I am able to execute also.

Could you please help me why this Steps are highlighted and shown as not defined

I am using : Eclipse Neon / cucumber 1.2.4

Comment: Do you have the eclipse cucumber plugin installed?

Comment: @Marit - Yes its installed, I have installed it from Eclipse Marketplace

Comment: So this is not to do with the steps running, but the fact that they aren't found in the ide and highlighted?